# Ideas on why my app won't run on Yocto RPi system?

Tags: linux, yocto

I've built a custom 32-bit non-GUI Raspberry Pi image using Yocto (Morty), built the corresponding SDK, and used the SDK's toolchain to build an app. When I run the app on the RPi, from a command prompt as root, the shell complains:

```
-sh: /path/to/app: No such file or directory
```

(with the real app name, obviously). `sh` is linked to `bash`. Here's what
I've checked:

1. The app exists, and is the correct executable.
2. Its execute permission bit is set.
3. Its ELF file format is the same as the ELF file format of every other command in the system.
4. The shared libraries it uses all exist, recursively, in /lib or
   /usr/lib. They are all listed by `ldconfig -p`.
5. There is no `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable.
6. If I run the app with `LL_DEBUG=all`, I get the same error, so it isn't even getting as far as loading libraries. (Or perhaps `LL_DEBUG` isn't supported on this build.)

Googling didn't turn up any other possibilities. Has anyone seen any other
reasons for this error? Or any ideas on how to diagnose it further?

---

In response to techraf:

1. If I had mistyped the name, I'd have gotten a "command not found" error. I tried running it by typing the full path. I also tried copying it into /bin and typing its name, in which case the error message showed the path in /bin.
2. `ls -l` showed the x attribute.
3. On the build system, `arm-poky-linux-objdump -f` (from the Yocto SDK) on the app executable showed `file format elf32-littlearm`, `architecture: arm, flags 0x00000112`, `EXEC_P, HAS_SYMS, D_PAGED`. If I did the same thing to, say, the `ls` command in the target rootfs in the build tree, it showed the same thing.
4. Using `arm-poky-linux-objdump -x` on the executable and grepping for `NEEDED`, I listed all libraries needed by the app executable, then did the same thing on all those libraries in the rootfs, and built a combined list. I then did `ldconfig -p` on the RPi, and verified that every library that was needed was in the list with the correct versions. Here are the relevant items from the list:

   ld-linux-armhf.so.3 (ELF) => /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3
   libasound.so.2 (libc6) => /usr/lib/libasound.so.2
   libc.so.6 (ELF, OS ABI: Linux 3.2.0) => /lib/libc.so.6
   libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (libc6) => /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
   libdl.so.2 (libc6, OS ABI: Linux 3.2.0) => /lib/libdl.so.2
   libgcc_s.so.1 (libc6) => /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
   libm.so.6 (libc6, OS ABI: Linux 3.2.0) => /lib/libm.so.6
   libpthread.so.0 (libc6, OS ABI: Linux 3.2.0) => /lib/libpthread.so.0
   librt.so.1 (libc6, OS ABI: Linux 3.2.0) => /lib/librt.so.1
   libstdc++.so.6 (libc6) => /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6

   I don't know what the parenthesized items in the list mean, so maybe there's a clue there.
5. I made sure there was no `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable.
6. I tried running `LL_DEBUG=all /path/to/app` and got the same error, with no library loading trace.

I understand that the `No such file or directory` error often means a missing library, but I've made sure all the libraries are there and properly cached. So I'm wondering if anyone else knows any other possible cause for this error.

---

I created an empty C project (just `return 0;` inside `main`), and got the same error message. I used `arm-poky-linux-objdump -x` on both it and the `chmod` command, which is the smallest executable my build's `/bin` directory. Everything was the same other than section addresses and sizes, except that my dummy program has one `.comment` section and `chmod` has one `.gnu_debuglink` section. Even the `.ARM.attributes` sections have the same contents. Yet `chmod` loads and runs, while my test program won't load even far enough for `ldd` to output any shared library activity. There has to be something wrong with the SDK toolchain, even though it was generated as part of the Linux build.

Comment: Instead of describing what you think the state is, please show the methods you used to check and their results.

Comment: I'm presuming `stat /path/to/app` using **the exact path from the error** proves this isn't just a typo or something...

Comment: I've edited the post to show what I did to check things out.

Comment: And goldilocks, stat-ing the file shows reasonable results.

Comment: ldd /path/to/app?

Comment: Since `ldd` is a script that tries to run the executable, this yields the same "no such file or directory" error message.

Comment: I ran one more test, and appended a message describing it to the original post. I hope someone else is still reading this.

Answer (score 0):

Someone on the Yocto list finally saw the problem: I was using the `-mfloat-abi=hard` option on the compile command, but I also needed to use the compiler to invoke the linker (instead of running ld directly), and use this same option.

The reason I didn't see this is that the program loader isn't listed in the object file as a NEEDED shared library. Instead, there's a string in a section called `.interp` that lists the name of the loader library.

Since I linked without `-mfloat-abi=hard`, it assumed `softfp`, which causes it to specify `/lib/ld-linux.so.3` as the loader (which doesn't exist in my build) instead of `/lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3`.

Thanks to all who tried to help.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.